# Separating part of mesh facing upwards

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-meshes

I really hope you can help me fix this code:

```
List<Vector3> verticesToExport = new List<Vector3>();//vertices of the triangles facing upwards.
        List<int> trianglesToExport = new List<int>();//new triangle facing upwards.
        //meshToCut is the original mesh, then I just try to replace it with the new data.
        int[] triangles = meshToCut.triangles;
        Vector3[] vertices = meshToCut.vertices;

        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 corner = vertices[triangles[i]];
            Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i + 1]] - corner;
            Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 2]] - corner;

            float projection = Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(b, a), Vector3.down);
            if (projection > 0f)
            {
                verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i]]);
                verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i + 1]]);
                verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i + 2]]);
                trianglesToExport.Add(triangles[i]);
                trianglesToExport.Add(triangles[i + 1]);
                trianglesToExport.Add(triangles[i + 2]);
            }
        }
        meshToCut.SetVertices(verticesToExport);
        meshToCut.SetTriangles(trianglesToExport, 0);//probably I'm doing wrong here!
```

It works great by retrieving the vertices facing up, and I guess the triangles too but when I put it into a mesh filter I believe the triangles are not in order...

1.The model I'm trying to separate; the triangles facing upwards.
[image: The model I'm trying to separate]
2. This is what happens if I just take the vertices and triangulate them again. It proves that vertices are alright!
[image: This is what happens if I just take the vertices and triangulate them again. It proves that vertices are alright!]

3. The result I get from the code above:
[image: The result I get from the code above]

Comment: What leads you to believe the triangles are not in order? What specific symptoms can we help diagnose and correct?

Comment: I've added some images so that it can explain itself better.
But I'm pretty sure the vertices are correct because of image 2, and triangles might not be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filling your `trianglesToExport` list with the indices these vertices had *in the original mesh*, rather than the indices they have in the new `verticesToExport` list.

A simple fix would be:

```
if (projection > 0f)
{
    // Fill the triangle index slots with the indices 
    // where we're *about* to write our vertices.
    trianglesToExport.Add(verticesToExport.Count);
    trianglesToExport.Add(verticesToExport.Count + 1);
    trianglesToExport.Add(verticesToExport.Count + 2);

    // Then fill those slots with the vertices from the original mesh.
    verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i]]);
    verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i + 1]]);
    verticesToExport.Add(vertices[triangles[i + 2]]);
    
}
```

But note that the way you're doing this here, you're going to be copying any shared vertices multiple times.

We can solve this by adding a dictionary that stores the mappings between indices of vertices in the original mesh, and indices of those vertices in our new subset. When we encounter a vertex, we first check if we've already mapped it, and if so, return that mapping. If not, we add it to our new subset and store the mapping for when we revisit it next.

```
int GetNewIndex( Dictionary<int, int> oldIndexToNew, int oldIndex, 
                 Vector3[] oldVertices, 
                 List<Vector3> verticesToExport) {

    if (!oldIndexToNew.TryGetValue(oldIndex, out int newIndex)) {
        newIndex = vecticesToExport.Count;
        verticesToExport.Add(oldVertices[oldIndex]);
        oldIndexToNew.Add(oldIndex, newIndex);
    }
    return newIndex;
}
```

Prep an empty dictionary when you start the slicing process. Then your loop can look like...

```
if (projection > 0f)
{     
    trianglesToExport.Add(GetNewIndex(oldIndexToNew, triangles[i],     vertices, verticesToExport));
    trianglesToExport.Add(GetNewIndex(oldIndexToNew, triangles[i + 1], vertices, verticesToExport));
    trianglesToExport.Add(GetNewIndex(oldIndexToNew, triangles[i + 2], vertices, verticesToExport));
}
```

Note that now we're not always adding three new vertices to the `verticesToExport` list for every triangle. Sometimes, some of the vertices are *already in the list*, and if so, we just re-use them by referring back to the existing index.

Comment: Yo are right on that I get too many vertices... so I get an error.
But I'm really confused here: oldIndexToNew.. what's gonna be the value each loop?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through a few loops with your debugger to find out.

Comment: Didn't really figure that out.
But since I have 3 vertices for each triangle I have no problem with the first code without dictionary. Thank you very much @DMGregory